# I`m looking for a equivalent in Spring of JavaAsync from Play Framework

Tags: spring, playframework

I wondering is there an equivalent of this feature from play framework

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaAsync

Basicly it helps to create more efective applications. Doesn anyone knows something like that for Spring Framework ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, Spring provides asynchronous processing via the `@Async` annotation.  See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support

Answer (score 0):

Not from Spring, but if you don't want/can't use Play, check [Akka](http://akka.io/), it provides similar tools.